# Почему js не хочет менять цвет фона?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background

***Вот исходник:***

```
function reverseRGBColor(rgbColor) {

  rgbColor = rgbColor.slice(4, rgbColor.length - 1)

  rgbColor = rgbColor.split(')')
  rgbColor = rgbColor.join()
  rgbColor = rgbColor.split(',')
  var r = parseInt(rgbColor[0])
  g = parseInt(rgbColor[1])
  b = parseInt(rgbColor[2])
  var rgbFullReversed = '';
  r = Math.abs(r - 255)
  g = Math.abs(g - 255)
  b = Math.abs(b - 255)
  rgbFullReversed = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`
  return rgbFullReversed
}
$("body").click(function(){
$("html").style.backgroundColor=reverseRGBColor($("html").style.backgroundColor)
     alert($("html").style.color)
     $("html").style.color=reverseRGBColor($("html").style.color)
})
```

Comment: В `jquery` стили элемента меняются методом `.css`. `element.style.property = 'value'` - это конструкция из "ванильного" js

Comment: html добавьте.. У Вас вообще есть color и background-color у body?

Answer (score 0):

`$("html")` - возвращает `jQuery` объект. У jQuery объекта нет свойства `style`.

Если нужно оперировать с html элементом, лучше сразу его и использовать без jQuery, а получать с помощью [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
$("body").click(function(){
    var html = document.querySelector('html');
    html.style.backgroundColor=reverseRGBColor(html.style.backgroundColor);
    alert(html.style.color);
    html.style.color=reverseRGBColor(html.style.color);
})
```

Comment: Grundy, не помогло

Comment: html.style.color все равно остаётся либо null, либо пустой строкой

Comment: @РусскийПуп, свойства в `.style` появляются если есть атрибут `style` у элемента. Если его нет, то все свойства из `style` будут пустыми строками. Это не относится к проблеме неверной работы с jquery объектами, которая описана в коде в вопросе